# InApp Purchase product list doesn't load in iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am trying to use a consumable InApp Purchase in my iPhone app. I am using [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) for reference. I have followed the tutorial correctly. But my products are not loading. Here is my code.

```
+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance {
static dispatch_once_t once;
static RageIAPHelper * sharedInstance;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                  @"com.ilfmobile.hero.twohundredconnects",
                                  @"com.ilfmobile.hero.onethousandconnects",
                                  nil];

 sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
});
return sharedInstance;
}
```

And my get product list code.

```
- (void)reload {
     products = nil;
     [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
     [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *theProducts) {

     [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
     if (success) {
        products = theProducts;
        [self.tblview reloadData];
    }
    }];
}
```

And I  implement the  InApp purchases in Xcode Capabilities. I have attached screenshots as below.[image: Screen shoot of xcode Capabilities.]

I have enabled InApp Purchases on iTunes Connect and added both of the products in the InApp list. [image: InApp purchases product list.]
[image: Screen shoot of add InApp purchase in my app.]

Please suggest where I am wrong. Thank you for giving your precious time to suggestion. I am using Xcode5.1 and my app development target iOS7.1

Comment: you mean that products = theProducts is nil? In this case theProducts is nil or products is nil?

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick feedback. i have solved my problem. this type of problem occur when we test the application on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen if you are not running your app in Device. ios simulator cause these type or issues.

Answer (score 0):

Create your certificates again and test your app in iPhone or iPad device.